# Получение дочерних элементов из JSON

Tags: javascript, json

Имею JSON файл, нужно получить все элементы urn;

```
[
    {
        "name": "One",
        "children": [{
                "urn": "urnOne"
            }, {
                "name": "ChildrenOne",
            }
        ]
    }, {
        "name": "Two",
        "children": [{
                "urn": "urnTwo"
            }, {
                "name": "ChildrenTwo",
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Мой код с этим не справляется.

```
fetch('./viewables.json')
  .then(response => ./json.json())
  .then(data => {
    data.forEach((el, i) => {  
      data[i].children.urn;
    })
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

children здесь представлен не как объект, а как массив, поэтому нужно указать, к какому порядковому элементу обратиться (в данном случае [0])

```
fetch('./viewables.json')
  .then(response => ./json.json())
  .then(data => {
    data.forEach((el, i) => {  
      data[i].children[0].urn;
    })
  });
```

Comment: Спасибо братан, то что надо!